# Removing elements from comments in Blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, css, comments, blogs

Blog URL:  http://theforeigntwo.blogspot.com.au

URL of concern:  http://theforeigntwo.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/steve-nash-post.html?showComment=1344125682577#c3764506429069823377

In the comments, there is a second "Reply" button at the bottom, filling about 400px, and an "Add comment" button about the same size, which I would like to remove.

The "Add comment" button seems redundant since there is already a comment form in place - it loads a larger comment form when clicked.

I'm not sure on which code to remove/modify, since it's so long. Could someone please tell me how to remove these extra buttons?

EDIT: I wasn't sure it was appropriate to share the code since it's so long, but here it is:

```
/* Comments
----------------------------------------------- */

span#commie {
  margin:0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color:#000000;
  font:15pt arial;
  background: #ffffff;
    padding:5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #939393;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #939393;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #939393;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
  }

.comments {
  width:565px;
  background:none;
  float:right;
  margin:0 25px 0 0;
  font:13pt arial;
}

.comments-content {
  font:13pt arial;
}

.comments .continue a, .comments .comment .comment-actions a {      /* THIS IS THE REPLY AND DELETE BUTTONS*/
    font:13pt arial;
    padding:5px;
    color: #000000;
  margin:0px 30px 20px 0;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
    background: #e9e9e9;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
}

.comments .continue a:hover, .comments .comment .comment-actions a:hover {
}

.comments .continue a:active, .comments .comment .comment-actions a:active {
}

.comments .comments-content .comment-thread ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: none;
}

.comments .comments-content .inline-thread {
    padding: 0px 0px 0 50px;
}

.comments .comments-content .comment-thread {
    margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;  
}

.comments .comments-content .comment-thread:empty {
    display: none;
}

.comments .comments-content .comment-replies {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.comments .comments-content .comment {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.comments .comments-content .comment:first-child {
}

.comments .comments-content .comment:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.comments .comments-content .comment-body {
    position: relative;
}

.comments .comments-content .comment-content {      /* THIS IS THE BODY OF EACH COMMENT, THE TEXT ITSELF */
  font:13pt arial;
  margin:10px 0 20px 0;
}

.comments .comment-block {      /* THIS IS EACH COMMENT BOX FROM AUTHOR TO DELETE */
  margin:0 0 50px 48px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
  background:#ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #939393;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #939393;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #939393;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.comments .comments-content .user {
}

.comments .comments-content .user a {
}

.comments .comments-content .user a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.comments .comments-content .icon.blog-author {
  background:purple;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 -4px 6px;
}

.comments .comments-content .datetime {
  padding:5px;
    margin-left: 6px; 
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 11px;
    float: right;
}

.comments .comments-content .owner-actions {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.comments .comments-replybox {
    border: none;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
}

.comments .comment-replybox-single {
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
}

.comments .comment-replybox-thread {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.comments .comments-content .loadmore a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

.comments .thread-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

.comments .comments-content .loadmore {
    cursor: pointer;
    max-height: 3em;
    margin-top: 3em;
}

.comments .comments-content .loadmore.loaded {
    max-height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.comments .thread-chrome.thread-collapsed {
    display: none;
}

.comments .thread-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
}

.comments .thread-toggle .thread-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 6px;
    width: 7px;
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 0.3em;
    padding-right: 4px;
}

.comments .thread-expanded .thread-arrow {
    data: image/png;
    base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAc AAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAG0lEQVR42mNgwAfKy8v/48I4FeA0AacVDFQBAP9wJkE/KhUMAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

.comments .thread-collapsed .thread-arrow {
    data: image/png;
    base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA AcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAJUlEQVR42mNgAILy8vL/DLgASBKnApgkVgXIkhgKiNKJ005s4gDLbCZBiSxfygAAAAB JRU5ErkJggg==") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}

.comments .avatar-image-container {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.comments .avatar-image-container img {
    width: 70px;
}




.deleted-comment {
  font-style:italic;
  color:gray;
  }
```

---

```
  <body>




<b:includable id='threaded_comment_js' var='post'>
  <script async='async' expr:src='data:post.commentSrc' type='text/javascript'/>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function() {
      var items = <data:post.commentJso/>;
      var msgs = <data:post.commentMsgs/>;
      var config = <data:post.commentConfig/>;

// <![CDATA[
      var cursor = null;
      if (items && items.length > 0) {
        cursor = parseInt(items[items.length - 1].timestamp) + 1;
      }

      var bodyFromEntry = function(entry) {
        if (entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
          for (var k in entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
            if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].name == 'blogger.contentRemoved') {
              return '<span class="deleted-comment">' + entry.content.$t + '</span>';
            }
          }
        }
        return entry.content.$t;
      }

      var parse = function(data) {
        cursor = null;
        var comments = [];
        if (data && data.feed && data.feed.entry) {
          for (var i = 0, entry; entry = data.feed.entry[i]; i++) {
            var comment = {};
            // comment ID, parsed out of the original id format
            var id = /blog-(\d+).post-(\d+)/.exec(entry.id.$t);
            comment.id = id ? id[2] : null;
            comment.body = bodyFromEntry(entry);
            comment.timestamp = Date.parse(entry.published.$t) + '';
            if (entry.author && entry.author.constructor === Array) {
              var auth = entry.author[0];
              if (auth) {
                comment.author = {
                  name: (auth.name ? auth.name.$t : undefined),
                  profileUrl: (auth.uri ? auth.uri.$t : undefined),
                  avatarUrl: (auth.gd$image ? auth.gd$image.src : undefined)
                };
              }
            }
            if (entry.link) {
              if (entry.link[2]) {
                comment.link = comment.permalink = entry.link[2].href;
              }
              if (entry.link[3]) {
                var pid = /.*comments\/default\/(\d+)\?.*/.exec(entry.link[3].href);
                if (pid && pid[1]) {
                  comment.parentId = pid[1];
                }
              }
            }
            comment.deleteclass = 'item-control blog-admin';
            if (entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
              for (var k in entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
                if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].name == 'blogger.itemClass') {
                  comment.deleteclass += ' ' + entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].value;
                } else if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].name == 'blogger.displayTime') {
                  comment.displayTime = entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].value;
                }
              }
            }
            comments.push(comment);
          }
        }
        return comments;
      };

      var paginator = function(callback) {
        if (hasMore()) {
          var url = config.feed + '?alt=json&v=2&orderby=published&reverse=false&max-results=50';
          if (cursor) {
            url += '&published-min=' + new Date(cursor).toISOString();
          }
          window.bloggercomments = function(data) {
            var parsed = parse(data);
            cursor = parsed.length < 50 ? null
                : parseInt(parsed[parsed.length - 1].timestamp) + 1
            callback(parsed);
            window.bloggercomments = null;
          }
          url += '&callback=bloggercomments';
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = url;
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
      };
      var hasMore = function() {
        return !!cursor;
      };
      var getMeta = function(key, comment) {
        if ('iswriter' == key) {
          var matches = !!comment.author
              && comment.author.name == config.authorName
              && comment.author.profileUrl == config.authorUrl;
          return matches ? 'true' : '';
        } else if ('deletelink' == key) {
          return config.baseUri + '/delete-comment.g?blogID='
               + config.blogId + '&postID=' + comment.id;
        } else if ('deleteclass' == key) {
          return comment.deleteclass;
        }
        return '';
      };

      var replybox = null;
      var replyUrlParts = null;
      var replyParent = undefined;

      var onReply = function(commentId, domId) {
        if (replybox == null) {
          // lazily cache replybox, and adjust to suit this style:
          replybox = document.getElementById('comment-editor');
          if (replybox != null) {
            replybox.height = '250px';
            replybox.style.display = 'block';
            replyUrlParts = replybox.src.split('#');
          }
        }
        if (replybox && (commentId !== replyParent)) {
          document.getElementById(domId).insertBefore(replybox, null);
          replybox.src = replyUrlParts[0]
              + (commentId ? '&parentID=' + commentId : '')
              + '#' + replyUrlParts[1];
          replyParent = commentId;
        }
      };

      var hash = (window.location.hash || '#').substring(1);
      var startThread, targetComment;
      if (/^comment-form_/.test(hash)) {
        startThread = hash.substring('comment-form_'.length);
      } else if (/^c[0-9]+$/.test(hash)) {
        targetComment = hash.substring(1);
      }

      // Configure commenting API:
      var configJso = {
        'maxDepth': config.maxThreadDepth
      };
      var provider = {
        'id': config.postId,
        'data': items,
        'loadNext': paginator,
        'hasMore': hasMore,
        'getMeta': getMeta,
        'onReply': onReply,
        'rendered': true,
        'initComment': targetComment,
        'initReplyThread': startThread,
        'config': configJso,
        'messages': msgs
      };

      var render = function() {
        if (window.goog && window.goog.comments) {
          var holder = document.getElementById('comment-holder');
          window.goog.comments.render(holder, provider);
        }
      };

      // render now, or queue to render when library loads:
      if (window.goog && window.goog.comments) {
        render();
      } else {
        window.goog = window.goog || {};
        window.goog.comments = window.goog.comments || {};
        window.goog.comments.loadQueue = window.goog.comments.loadQueue || [];
        window.goog.comments.loadQueue.push(render);
      }
    })();
// ]]>
  </script>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='backlinks' var='post'>
  <a name='links'/><h4><data:post.backlinksLabel/></h4>
  <b:if cond='data:post.numBacklinks != 0'>
    <dl class='comments-block' id='comments-block'>
      <b:loop values='data:post.backlinks' var='backlink'>
        <div class='collapsed-backlink backlink-control'>
          <dt class='comment-title'>
            <span class='backlink-toggle-zippy'>&#160;</span>
            <a expr:href='data:backlink.url' rel='nofollow'><data:backlink.title/></a>
            <b:include data='backlink' name='backlinkDeleteIcon'/>
          </dt>
          <dd class='comment-body collapseable'>
            <data:backlink.snippet/>
          </dd>
          <dd class='comment-footer collapseable'>
            <span class='comment-author'><data:post.authorLabel/> <data:backlink.author/></span>
            <span class='comment-timestamp'><data:post.timestampLabel/> <data:backlink.timestamp/></span>
          </dd>
        </div>
      </b:loop>
    </dl>
  </b:if>
  <p class='comment-footer'>
    <a class='comment-link' expr:href='data:post.createLinkUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_backlinks-create-link&quot;' target='_blank'><data:post.createLinkLabel/></a>
  </p>
</b:includable>

</b:includable>
<b:includable id='comment-form' var='post'>
  <div class='comment-form'>
    <a name='comment-form'/>
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
      <h4 id='comment-post-message'>
        <a expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_comment-editor-toggle-link&quot;' href='javascript:void(0)'><data:postCommentMsg/></a></h4>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' frameborder='0' height='410' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' style='display: none' width='100%'/>
    <b:else/>
      <h4 id='comment-post-message'/>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' frameborder='0' height='410' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' width='100%'/>
    </b:if>
    <data:post.friendConnectJs/>
    <data:post.cmtfpIframe/>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      BLOG_CMT_createIframe(&#39;<data:post.appRpcRelayPath/>&#39;, &#39;<data:post.communityId/>&#39;);
    </script>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='threaded_comments' var='post'>
  <div class='comments' id='comments'>
    <a name='comments'/>
    <span id='commie'>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 0'>0 comments yet! </b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 1'>Only 1 comment! </b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 2'>2 comments now! </b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 3'>3 comments today! </b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments &gt; 3'>More than 3 comments! </b:if>
</span>


    <div class='comments-content'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.embedCommentForm'>
        <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comment_js'/>
      </b:if>
      <div id='comment-holder'>
         <data:post.commentHtml/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class='comment-footer'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.allowNewComments'>
        <b:include data='post' name='threaded-comment-form'/>
      <b:else/>
        <data:post.noNewCommentsText/>
      </b:if>
    </p>

    <b:if cond='data:showCmtPopup'>
      <div id='comment-popup'>
        <iframe allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' id='comment-actions' name='comment-actions' scrolling='no'>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <div id='backlinks-container'>
    <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_backlinks-container&quot;'>
       <b:if cond='data:post.showBacklinks'>
         <b:include data='post' name='backlinks'/>
       </b:if>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='backlinkDeleteIcon' var='backlink'>
  <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:backlink.adminClass'>
    <a expr:href='data:backlink.deleteUrl' expr:title='data:top.deleteBacklinkMsg'>
      <img src='//www.blogger.com/img/icon_delete13.gif'/>
    </a>
  </span>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='mobile-nextprev'>
  <div class='blog-pager' id='blog-pager'>
    <b:if cond='data:newerPageUrl'>
      <div class='mobile-link-button' id='blog-pager-newer-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'>&amp;lsaquo;</a>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <b:if cond='data:olderPageUrl'>
      <div class='mobile-link-button' id='blog-pager-older-link'>
      <a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'>&amp;rsaquo;</a>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <div class='mobile-link-button' id='blog-pager-home-link'>
    <a class='home-link' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:homeMsg/></a>
    </div>

    <div class='mobile-desktop-link'>
      <a class='home-link' expr:href='data:desktopLinkUrl'><data:desktopLinkMsg/></a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class='clear'/>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='mobile-post' var='post'>
  <div class='date-outer'>
    <div class='date-posts'>
      <div class='post-outer'>





        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
          <b:else/>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
          <b:else/>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='postQuickEdit' var='post'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.editUrl'>
    <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:post.adminClass'>
      <a expr:href='data:post.editUrl' expr:title='data:top.editPostMsg'>
        <img alt='' class='icon-action' height='18' src='http://img2.blogblog.com/img/icon18_edit_allbkg.gif' width='18'/>
      </a>
    </span>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='main' var='top'>
  <b:if cond='data:mobile == &quot;false&quot;'>

    <!-- posts -->
    <div class='blog-posts hfeed'>

      <b:include data='top' name='status-message'/>

      <data:defaultAdStart/>
      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>

        <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>
          &lt;div class=&quot;date-posts&quot;&gt;
        </b:if>
        <div class='post-outer'>
        <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
          <b:else/>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.showThreadedComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
          <b:else/>
            <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
        </div>
        <b:if cond='data:post.includeAd'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
            <data:defaultAdEnd/>
          <b:else/>
            <data:adEnd/>
          </b:if>
          <div class='inline-ad'>
            <data:adCode/>
          </div>
          <data:adStart/>
        </b:if>
      </b:loop>
      <b:if cond='data:numPosts != 0'>
        &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
      </b:if>
      <data:adEnd/>
    </div>

    <!-- navigation -->
    <b:include name='nextprev'/>

    <!-- feed links -->
    <b:include name='feedLinks'/>

    <b:if cond='data:top.showStars'>
      <script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'/>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load(&quot;annotations&quot;, &quot;1&quot;, {&quot;locale&quot;: &quot;<data:top.languageCode/>&quot;});
        function initialize() {
          google.annotations.setApplicationId(<data:top.blogspotReviews/>);
          google.annotations.createAll();
          google.annotations.fetch();
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
      </script>
    </b:if>

  <b:else/>
    <b:include name='mobile-main'/>
  </b:if>

  <b:if cond='data:top.showDummy'>
    <data:top.dummyBootstrap/>
  </b:if>

</b:includable>
<b:includable id='commentDeleteIcon' var='comment'>
  <span expr:class='&quot;item-control &quot; + data:comment.adminClass'>
    <b:if cond='data:showCmtPopup'>
      <div class='goog-toggle-button'>
        <div class='goog-inline-block comment-action-icon'/>
      </div>
    <b:else/>
      <a class='comment-delete' expr:href='data:comment.deleteUrl' expr:title='data:top.deleteCommentMsg'>
        <img src='//www.blogger.com/img/icon_delete13.gif'/>
      </a>
    </b:if>
  </span>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='feedLinks'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'> <!-- Blog feed links -->
    <b:if cond='data:feedLinks'>
      <div class='blog-feeds'>
        <b:include data='feedLinks' name='feedLinksBody'/>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <b:else/> <!--Post feed links -->
    <div class='post-feeds'>
      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.feedLinks'>
            <b:include data='post.feedLinks' name='feedLinksBody'/>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
      </b:loop>
    </div>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='threaded-comment-form' var='post'>
  <div class='comment-form'>
    <a name='comment-form'/>
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' frameborder='0' height='410' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' style='display: none' width='100%'/>
    <b:else/>
      <p><data:blogCommentMessage/></p>
      <data:blogTeamBlogMessage/>
      <a expr:href='data:post.commentFormIframeSrc' id='comment-editor-src'/>
      <iframe allowtransparency='true' class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' frameborder='0' height='410' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor' src='' width='100%'/>
    </b:if>
    <data:post.friendConnectJs/>
    <data:post.cmtfpIframe/>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      BLOG_CMT_createIframe(&#39;<data:post.appRpcRelayPath/>&#39;, &#39;<data:post.communityId/>&#39;);
    </script>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='mobile-index-post' var='post'>
  <div class='mobile-date-outer date-outer'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.dateHeader'>
      <div class='date-header'>
        <span><data:post.dateHeader/></span>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <div class='mobile-post-outer'>
      <a expr:href='data:post.url'>
        <h3 class='mobile-index-title entry-title' itemprop='name'>
          <data:post.title/>
        </h3>

        <div class='mobile-index-arrow'>&amp;rsaquo;</div>

        <div class='mobile-index-contents'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
            <div class='mobile-index-thumbnail'>
              <div class='Image'>
                <img expr:src='data:post.thumbnailUrl'/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </b:if>

          <div class='post-body'>
            <b:if cond='data:post.snippet'><data:post.snippet/></b:if>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div style='clear: both;'/>
      </a>

      <div class='mobile-index-comment'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
            <b:if cond='data:post.numComments != 0'>
              <a class='comment-link' expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick'>
                <data:post.commentLabelFull/>:
              </a>
            </b:if>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='feedLinksBody' var='links'>
  <div class='feed-links'>
  <data:feedLinksMsg/>
  <b:loop values='data:links' var='f'>
     <a class='feed-link' expr:href='data:f.url' expr:type='data:f.mimeType' target='_blank'><data:f.name/> (<data:f.feedType/>)</a>
  </b:loop>
  </div>
</b:includable>
<b:includable id='comments' var='post'>
  <div class='comments' id='comments'>
    <a name='comments'/>
    <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>

    <span id='commie'>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 0'>0 comments yet! </b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 1'>Only 1 comment! </b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 2'>2 comments now! </b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments == 3'>3 comments today! </b:if>
<b:if cond='data:post.numComments &gt; 3'>More than 3 comments! </b:if>
</span>


      <b:if cond='data:post.commentPagingRequired'>
        <span class='paging-control-container'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.hasOlderLinks'>
            <a expr:class='data:post.oldLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.oldestLinkUrl'><data:post.oldestLinkText/></a>
              &#160;
            <a expr:class='data:post.oldLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.olderLinkUrl'><data:post.olderLinkText/></a>
              &#160;
          </b:if>

          <data:post.commentRangeText/>

          <b:if cond='data:post.hasNewerLinks'>
            &#160;
            <a expr:class='data:post.newLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.newerLinkUrl'><data:post.newerLinkText/></a>
            &#160;
            <a expr:class='data:post.newLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.newestLinkUrl'><data:post.newestLinkText/></a>
          </b:if>
        </span>
      </b:if>

      <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_comments-block-wrapper&quot;'>
        <dl expr:class='data:post.avatarIndentClass' id='comments-block'>

          <b:loop values='data:post.comments' var='comment'>
            <dt expr:class='&quot;comment-author &quot; + data:comment.authorClass' expr:id='data:comment.anchorName'>
              <b:if cond='data:comment.favicon'>
                <img expr:src='data:comment.favicon' height='16px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;' width='16px'/>
              </b:if>
              <a expr:name='data:comment.anchorName'/>
              <b:if cond='data:blog.enabledCommentProfileImages'>
                <data:comment.authorAvatarImage/>
              </b:if>
              <b:if cond='data:comment.authorUrl'>
                <a expr:href='data:comment.authorUrl' rel='nofollow'><data:comment.author/></a>
              <b:else/>
                <data:comment.author/>
              </b:if>
              just had to say...
            </dt>
            <dd class='comment-body' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + data:comment.cmtBodyIdPostfix'>
              <b:if cond='data:comment.isDeleted'>
                <span class='deleted-comment'><data:comment.body/></span>
              <b:else/>
                <p>
<span class='comment-timestamp'>
                <a expr:href='data:comment.url' title='comment permalink'>
                  <data:comment.timestamp/>
                </a>
                <b:include data='comment' name='commentDeleteIcon'/>
              </span>

                  <data:comment.body/>
                </p>
              </b:if>
            </dd>
            <dd class='comment-footer'>

            </dd>
          </b:loop>
        </dl>
      </div>

      <b:if cond='data:post.commentPagingRequired'>
        <span class='paging-control-container'>
          <a expr:class='data:post.oldLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.oldestLinkUrl'>
            <data:post.oldestLinkText/>
          </a>
          <a expr:class='data:post.oldLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.olderLinkUrl'>
            <data:post.olderLinkText/>
          </a>
          &#160;
          <data:post.commentRangeText/>
          &#160;
          <a expr:class='data:post.newLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.newerLinkUrl'>
            <data:post.newerLinkText/>
          </a>
          <a expr:class='data:post.newLinkClass' expr:href='data:post.newestLinkUrl'>
            <data:post.newestLinkText/>
          </a>
        </span>
      </b:if>

      <p class='comment-footer'>
        <b:if cond='data:post.embedCommentForm'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.allowNewComments'>
            <b:include data='post' name='comment-form'/>
          <b:else/>
            <data:post.noNewCommentsText/>
          </b:if>
        <b:else/>
          <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
            <a expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick'><data:postCommentMsg/></a>
          </b:if>
        </b:if>

      </p>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:showCmtPopup'>
      <div id='comment-popup'>
        <iframe allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0' id='comment-actions' name='comment-actions' scrolling='no'>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </b:if>

    <div id='backlinks-container'>
    <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_backlinks-container&quot;'>
       <b:if cond='data:post.showBacklinks'>
         <b:include data='post' name='backlinks'/>
       </b:if>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
</b:section>
      </div>
```

Comment: without you showing us the code, we can't help

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "Replay" button, there are several things you could do:

```
    #bc_0_0MN {
    display:none !important;
    }
```

2.

```
   .comment-actions secondary-text {
   display:none !important;
   }
```

Let me know if you need more assistance with this section.